# pre-image of intersection

Tags: functions

This is a basic question and I know this is typically not how this is proven but I was wondering if the following is a valid proof of showing that given two disjoint sets, say V and W in the co-domain, their pre-images are also disjoint:

If we assume that the pre-image($V$) and pre-image($W$) had an intersection, the points in the intersection would be in the pre-image of $V$, and the same points would be in the pre-image of $W$ and so from the definition of pre-image $f$(these points) would map to both $V$ and $W$ at the same time since $V$ and $W$ are disjoint, but this can’t be because $f$ is a function.  Thus a contradiction and so our assumption that pre-image($V$) and pre-image($W$) had an intersection is wrong and so pre-image($V$) and pre-image($W$) are disjoint.

Comment: Looks good. Of course it's also true that for any family (indexed by a set of any cardinality) of sets $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$, we have $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}U_\alpha) = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$. Pre-images are very nice.

Comment: The logic seems fine. Using some symbols would clarify your argument, though. Also, how is this not the typical way of proving the statement? It seems pretty standard to me...